# FacebookAuthorizationException: UnknownError: remote_app_id does not match stored id on FB SDK 3.5

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I've tried all on FB page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/

and ANY solution published as a response to:
[Facebook message remote_app_id does not match stored id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666829/facebook-message-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stored-id)
[error: remote_app_id does not match stored id with correct heyhash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16890092/error-remote-app-id-does-not-match-stored-id-with-correct-heyhash)

and I still keep getting the following:

com.parse.ParseException: com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException: UnknownError: remote_app_id does not match stored id

I'm using Parse:

I even tried to change package name/ create new FB app  but nothing helped.

Same for SDK 3, 3.5.

The context of the exception:

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(Arrays.asList("email", Permissions.Friends.ABOUT_ME),
                this, new LogInCallback() {
          @Override
          public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
              if (user == null) {
                  ...
```

I was already tried anything- generating the hash key using both code and openSSL (both yielded the same hash).

Would thank your kind help.

Frustrated developer

Comment: That error means your key hash does not match what's stored in your app settings. Try regenerating your key hash, using both debug AND release key stores.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try Generate  keyhash and included in your  developer.facebook.com  (corresponding app)
```

TO GENERATE KEYHASH

```
private void generateKeyHash() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "Your Package name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:",
                    Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you put the initialize code in your Application.onCreate()?

```
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(PARSE_FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
```